# NDsolve taking value of previous time step

Tags: differential-equations

I am using de NDsolve code below:

```
NDSolve[{r''[t] - phi'[t]^2 r[t] + 
    9.8 (Sin[phi[t]] - 0.7*Cos[phi[t]]) == 0, 
  1.2 (1 + 20*(r[t]^2 + 2^2 + 4 r[t] Sin[phi[t]])^2) phi''[t] + 
    phi'[t] + phi[t] == 50 Sin[4 t], 
  phi[0] == phi'[0] == r[0] == r'[0] == 0, 
  WhenEvent[r[t] > 1, {r[t] -> 0.99998, r'[t] -> 0}], 
  WhenEvent[r[t] < -1, {r[t] -> -0.99998, r'[t] -> 0}], 
  WhenEvent[{0.7 Cos[phi[t]] > Sin[phi[t]], 
    r'[t] == 0}, {r[t] -> r[t - 1], r'[t] -> 0}]}, {r, phi}, {t, 0, 
  1000}]
```

The problem appeares in the last `WhenEvent`, i want when that condition is True ($0.7Cos\phi>Sin\phi$ and $r'[t]=0$), the value of $r(t)$ takes the value of previous iteration and the velocity don't change.

Does Someone know how to solve it?

Thank you so much

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Your last WhenEvent  uses `r[t] -> r[t - 1]` to calculate the last timestep.  I think it's wrong, because you can't know wether actual  timestep equals 1!